# Does Weblogic expose metrics through Jmx

Tags: weblogic, jmx, prometheus

Does weblogic expose metrics through Jmx so it can be monitor with prometheus ?
What is the best solution to monitor weblogic servers (threads, datasources...) ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. WebLogic Server expose all its configuration and runtime metrics through a JMX interface. See this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/JMXPG/understanding.htm#JMXPG114) for details.
The Oracle WebLogic Server blogs publishes several articles about weblogic and prometheus. This [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/use-prometheus-and-grafana-to-monitor-weblogic-server-on-kubernetes) explains how use Prometheus and Grafana with WebLogic server for instance.

Comment: Can we use exporter without using kubernetes? Is that possible? I have no idea on Kubernetes/docker.

Comment: Why are you talking about Kubernetes ? Don't need it to run WebLogic.

Comment: No, I am talking about the WebLogic monitoring exporter. I am trying to scrape metric from WebLogic using the exporter and feed it to prometheus/Grafana. All docs from Oracle uses Kubernetes.. Can we use this exporter without Kubernetes? Any refernece you have? Thanks!

Comment: Kubernetes is not required at all. Start with this [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/exporting-metrics-from-weblogic-server) about the exporter. You can write your own.